# Flywheels and work

Tags: momentum, work, rotational-kinematics

I'll start with a scenario for some control in the concepts I'm asking about today.
Forgive me in advance, I never had the chance to explore physics in school, but I'd be happy to learn something new here.

Let's say I have 3 different fly wheels, all 3 of them have a handle in the middle to hand-crank them. The first two flywheels have fixed weights on them. One with one weight on each spoke positioned towards the outside of the wheel, and the other having its weights towards the center.

the 3rd wheel has weights that will, at a certain point of operation (and likely controlled electronically), "drop" from the center and move towards the outer wheel.

Over simplified example where weights can be considered evenly distributed, **the question comes down something like this:**
would it be any easier to rotate a wheel where most of the weight is in the center compared to  a wheel where the weights would be on the ends of the spokes?

**second question:**
if there is a difference in work needed to rotate the wheels, would the wheel with a delayed deployment of the weights have any kind of advantage, such as extra momentum allowing for increased or prolonged output?

**Bonus Question:**
Thank you for the prompt answer, so here's an ancillary question.

Related to this theoretical third wheel, would the initial slowing of deploying the weights be enough to cause my initial amount of hand cranked work to be in vain? or would the pre-crank, combined with the weights moving outwards make my overall effort less than if i had simply tried cranking the fixed wheel with the weight already shifted towards the outer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Related to this theoretical third wheel, would the initial slowing of
>   deploying the weights be enough to cause my initial amount of hand
>   cranked work to be in vain? or would the pre-crank, combined with the
>   weights moving outwards make my overall effort less than if i had
>   simply tried cranking the fixed wheel with the weight already shifted
>   towards the outer.

It would be worse.  You have to crank enough to both spin the wheel and to make the weights move radially (KE).  Unless you have some very elaborate mechanism, the KE from the radial motion of the weights will be lost as they slam into the rim.

It would be more efficient to leave the weights in one position.  You could use an efficient gearing if you need to begin with a lower torque.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the exchange.

When you ask "would it be easier to rotate", there are two different answers. If you mean, would it be easier to accelerate the wheel to some predetermined speed, the answer is yes. If you mean would it be easier to maintain that speed, the answer is no.

For a rotating body, you need to learn about angular momentum, and angular moments of inertia. In this case, you can think of the problem just like moving an object in a straight line, except: you replace force with torque (force times radius), and you replace velocity with angular velocity (v times radius) and you replace mass with angular moment of inertia (which gets complicated quickly, but for a point mass m is m times r squared). For a wheel with the weights near the axle, r is less than when they are at the rim, so the moment of inertia is less.

Second question. If the weights are dropped at some point, the wheel will immediately slow down, due to conservation of angular momentum, m times angular velocity. The clichéd (but still accurate) example is a spinning skater who extends her arms and immediately slows down. If you have access to a good swivel chair you can see this for yourself. Sit down and start spinning. If you extend and then fold your legs the chair will slow down and then speed up. So the answer to that is no, it won't do any good for prolonging the spin, assuming that the maximum spin rate is the same in all cases. When the weights are near the axle the wheel has less energy (for a given spin rate) than when the weights are at the rim. This is directly related to the fact that the wheel is easier to spin up with the weights at the center. You put less work in, you get less work out.